# MS-ACCESS Calling Excel function Median

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, median

Hi I am trying to load excel function Median to a MS-ACCESS via this function:

```
Public Function excel() As Integer
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim i As Long
    Dim p, p2 As Double
    Dim a(), b()
    Dim res As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("testovaci")

    Dim oExcel As Object
    Set oExcel = CreateObject("excel.application")

    rs.MoveFirst
    p = rs.RecordCount
    ReDim a(p)
    ReDim b(p)
    For i = 0 To p - 1
    a(i) = rs.Fields("cislo").Value
    rs.MoveNext
    'Debug.Print a(i)
    Next i

    For i = 0 To p - 1
    If i = 0 Then
    res = a(i)
    Else
    res = res & ", " & a(i)
    End If
    Debug.Print res

    Next i

    excel = oExcel.Worksheetfunction.Median(res)

End Function
```

And if I type in parameters into function like this:

```
excel = oExcel.Worksheetfunction.Median(1, 2, 3)
```

then it works, but if i try to pass a string with values res=1,2,3 then it doesn't work.
DO you have any idea how to fill this function with ms-access data to make it work please?

Comment: Pass the function an array of values, not a concatenated string.

Comment: And how can I do that? If I say `excel = oExcel.Worksheetfunction.Median(a())` then it calculates it from the last record only. a() is an array with values I need to get median from. I know that beacuse my array have these numbers: 5, 8, 9, 4, 23, 45, 888, 88, 99, 10, 11, 12 and resault says 12

Comment: The result of `WorksheetFunction.Median(Array(5, 8, 9, 4, 23, 45, 888, 88, 99, 10, 11, 12))` is `11.5`.

Comment: Yes it works thank you! I've found the mistake I declared function as integer and it should be double, but because it gaves me the same value as the last record I haven't seen that problem :)

Comment: You don't even have to use Excel for this: [VBA.Quartiles](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Quartiles).

Comment: Thank you @Gustav that's a nice function, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong, but when I use this function based on a query It tells me: Run-time error '3061' : Too few parameters. Expected 4. in a debug window my sql looks like this: `Select [TASK] From [testForm2] Where [TASK]='(ITEM)' Order By [TASK] Asc`

Comment: Don't know about that query. As for the median and the `DMedian` function, study the documentation and the demo.

Comment: @Gustav The problem with the query is probably, that I set the criteria like this:`<[Form]![testForm2]![crit1] And >[Form]![testForm2]![crit2]` and `<[Form]![testForm2]![Age1] And >[Form]![testForm2]![Age2]` which makes 4 parameters. When I delete these parameters Median function works well

Comment: If you run this query from code, it will not know the values from the form. If you open the query "manually", the form must be open.

Comment: @Gustav even when the Form is open and all the criteria are set, Function always end up with this error. Usually when the criteria are not set from the form Access give you option to set them manually, but that's not what happens here.

Comment: Perhaps you should append the query to your question.

Comment: @Gustav I've made entirely new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58976465/microsoft-office-access-median-function-too-few-parameters/58983859#58983859

Answer (score 1):

There were two problems:

1. Pass array to a function not a string `excel = oExcel.Worksheetfunction.Median(a())`
2. My entire function was declares as integer but I wanted result from double `Public Function excel() As DOUBLE`